# Remove double quotes from jquery array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var alldata = 'name', 88, 89, 50;


var myArray = [];     / Declare an array variable. Array index starts with 0 /
       myArray[0] =  ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit']; / Assigning array type values to myArray elements /
       myArray[1] =  alldata;

    alert(myArray);
```

this is the i am creating in jquery but whenever i show the data it will show this:

"'name', 88, 89, 50"

but i dont want to show the double quotes i just want to show the answer like:

'name', 88, 89, 50

Comment: Check for error in console...

Comment: `thatString.split(',')`

Comment: what is `typeof alldata` ? Let me guess, string ? Also, Have you wonder if the quotes aren't added by the `alert` dialog ?? What's the result if you do `console.log(myArray)` instead ?!

Comment: @TCHdvlp yes data is in string but i have convert this in array.

Comment: Your code as shown won't even run: `var alldata = 'name', 88, 89, 50;` is a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding values dynamically in array use .replace('"','');
for each element in loop.